# Fetching a sub element only using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please see the following code:

```
<div id="song" class="s1">
<div class = "l">foo</div>
<div class="r">
<div>foo</div><div>foo</div>
<div class="link"><a href="some url">Link</a></div>
</div></div>
<div id="song" class="s2">
<div class = "l">foo</div>
<div class="r">
<div>foo</div><div>foo</div>
<div class="link"><a href="some url">Link</a></div>
</div></div>
<div id="song" class="s3">
<div class = "l">foo</div>
<div class="r">
<div>foo</div><div>foo</div>
<div class="link"><a href="some url">Link</a></div>
</div></div>
```

There are several more s like these. I've to get the link from the first `<div>` whose ID is song only using JavaScript because I've fetched this data using php into an `<object>` tag.

Thank you :)

Comment: `ID` should be **UNIQUE**, this is *invalid*

Comment: That is true, but this is the code that I have to work with. Is it possible to get the link from this code?

Comment: EDIT: I've to fetch the data from the link in the first DIV

Comment: add into class instead of id...it will work..

Comment: You are missing 3 </div>...

Answer (score 0):

You should use JQuery like (at the bottom of your file):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var links = $.map($('div#song .link a'), function(a) { return $(a).attr('href'); });
console.log(links);
</script>
```

Output:

```
["some url", "some url", "some url"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting only the first set,

```
<div id="song1" class="s1">
<div class = "l">foo</div>
<div class="r">
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div class="link"><a href="some url">Link</a></div>
</div>
```

You can get the link which is some url by

```
var link = $(".s1").find("a");
console.log(link.attr('href') );
```

Comment: This is inside an `<object>` tag. When I run this code, the output says undefined.

Comment: It should still work. Can you give more details on what's printed in console.log?

Comment: the only thing it says is `undefined`

Comment: Have you included jquery?  http://jsfiddle.net/quik_silv/Uf985/ and you should put the code inside $(document).ready(function() { ... });